# Error including Kernel Header files in C, compiled using clang

Tags: bpf

I am writing an eBPF Code.
I need to use the function `bpf_obj_pin`, declared in kernel files:

- `tools/lib/bpf/bpf.c`
- `tools/lib/bpf/bpf.h`

Refer from here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/bpf_obj_pin

So from the same files, I found out that I had to include this in my header.

```
#include <bpf/bpf.h>
```

But I get the following **ERROR**:

```
clang -O2 -target bpf -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c bpf1.c -o bpf1.o
bpf1.c:10:10: fatal error: 'bpf/bpf.h' file not found
#include <bpf/bpf.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
makefile:21: recipe for target 'bpf1.o' failed
make: *** [bpf1.o] Error 1
```

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895179/how-to-build-bpf-program-out-of-the-kernel-tree) is somewhat similar but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried installing https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf?

Comment: No, I will try it and let you know. Thanks for the suggestion.